# pymongo db.command exclude fields / projection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to write a call to db.command() using PyMongo that performs a geoNear search and I would like to exclude fields.  The documentation for db.runCommand on the Mongo site and the PyMongo documentation both do not explain how one can accomplish this.

I understand how to do this using db.collection.find():

```
response = collection.find_one(
  filter = {"PostalCode": postal_code},
  projection = {'_id': False}
)
```

However, I cannot find any example anywhere of how to accomplish this when performing a geoNear search utilizing db.command():

```
params = {
  "near": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
  },
  "spherical": True,
  "limit": 1,
}

response = self.db.command("geoNear", value=self._collection_name, **params)
```

Can anyone provide insight into how one excludes fields when using db.command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geoNear command does not have a "projection" feature. It always returns entire documents. See the geoNear command reference for its options:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/